# php special chars (umlaute) from URL

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm getting mad with this utf8 and ansi and ascii stuff. Always the same old story...

I have an url that includes a GET parameter: 
[http://www.example.com/?c=Österreich](http://www.example.com/?c=%C3%96sterreich)

In my PHP script, I make a switch:

```
switch ( strtolower( $country ) ) {
  case "deutschland":
    $country = "DE";
    break;

  case "österreich":
    $country = "AT";
    break;

  case "schweiz":
    $country = "CH";
    break;

  default:
    $country = "DE";
    break;
}
```

For Östereich, I get the default value "DE". So how to solve this?

Comment: Use `osterreich` instad of `österreich`. And pass same from URL.

Comment: Are you using urlencode() function? http://php.net/manual/tr/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Try to var_dump(strtolower($country)) so you can see what output you are dealing with.

Comment: This is a good occasion to mention [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use multibyte functions to manage UTF8 strings, so mb_strtolower() instead of strtolower()